# Is it possible to checkout git remote branch to gerrit based workspace?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have created  git local branch and pushed to remote server.

```
    git push origin git_based_branch_test
```

Then I updated my current workspace with  repo init/sync  to update to Gerrit based repository.  All my local branches created using git commands is gone.

```
   repo start <git_based_branch_test>
```

is getting created as new branch without my earlier changes.  So can help me how to pull  git_based_branch_test  using repo start ?

Comment: Rather than push branches to your Gerrit server, you push "change-sets". I would recommend using a tool like "git-review" for this

Comment: My question is related to fetching the existing remote branch which was  created using git commands,  to Gerrit repository.   push has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following inside the repository and you'll create a local git_based_branch_test tracking the remote git_based_branch_test (origin/git_based_branch_test)

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout git_based_branch_test

Branch git_based_branch_test set up to track remote branch git_based_branch_test from origin by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'git_based_branch_test'
```